# Excel 2007 Query editor - greater than function

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to edit some code in an Excel 2007 SQL database query editor.

The current code is (excerpt only):

```
(Select NVL(Sum(Shut_Hours),0) 
   From Shut_Hrs_Calc SHC2 
  Where BDT.Prod_Day=SHC2.Prod_Day And SHC2.Equipment_ID = 1006) As CD1C,
```

The code should only return shut hours by date in each cell of the table (Shut_Hrs_Calc) that are less than or equal to 24 hours, however it is returning values higher than 24 hours. I want to edit the above code so that for any Shut_Hours that are greater than 24 it returns a value of 24 in that cell of the table. If it's not greater than 24 then return that value. If null return 0 (as  the current code already does).

Help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Example table is below:

```
MAINT_DATE  CD1C
27/09/2018  0
28/09/2018  0
29/09/2018  0
30/09/2018  0
1/10/2018   0
2/10/2018   0
3/10/2018   0
4/10/2018   0
5/10/2018   0
6/10/2018   0
7/10/2018   0
8/10/2018   0
9/10/2018   0
10/10/2018  0
11/10/2018  0
12/10/2018  0
13/10/2018  0
14/10/2018  13
15/10/2018  25
16/10/2018  35
17/10/2018  24
18/10/2018  24
19/10/2018  16
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a case statement, e.g.:

```
(Select case when sum(Shut_Hours) > 24 then 24
             else nvl(sum(shut_hours), 0)
        end 
 From Shut_Hrs_Calc SHC2 
 Where BDT.Prod_Day=SHC2.Prod_Day And SHC2.Equipment_ID = 1006) As CD1C
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `least()` and `coalesce()`:

```
(Select least(coalesce(Sum(Shut_Hours), 0), 24)
 From Shut_Hrs_Calc SHC2 
 Where BDT.Prod_Day = SHC2.Prod_Day And 
       SHC2.Equipment_ID = 1006
) As CD1C,
```